# Marketing Cloud No Contacts after import and setting as root

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

I've imported some records into a data extension and in the Data Designer I've marked them as the root DE

I can see the records in the data extension but when I look at All Contacts in the Contact Builder I don't see any contacts.

I have read the documentation but I can't find where I'm going wrong, anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have to use a string as the primary key in order to be able to establish the relationship between a Contact and a row in a data extension

Answer (score 0):

They aren't actually a Contact until they exist in All Contacts. I.e. Import the same records to All Subscribers.

A single automation can import your data into two places.